# How can i display image in IE using base64 encoding method?

Tags: html, gwt, encoding

I want to display image using base64 encoding in IE using GWT

If it is not possible can u please suggest me the alternate way except creating the image to serverside & sending URL to the client side

Can u help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the syntax is:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,DATA" />
```

where `DATA` is the base64-encoded image. However, IE doesn't support images of that form natively. It will work if you include the [IE7 javascript library](http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/) though, using [this trick](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/06/base64-ie/)

Comment: but i am not using PHP , i am using Sevlet